# Use Node.js data in HTML with HAPI

Tags: html, node.js, hapi.js

I have a *server.js* page and it get datas from database. I want to use this datas in a HTML page. How can I get this datas.

**I don't use Express** but Hapi (because i'm happy lol).

This is my code :

```
            <script>var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');
            var graph = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'line',
              data: {
                labels: ['Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi', 'Dimanche'],
                datasets: [{
                  label: 'CPU',
                  data: [22, 19, 25, 65, 30, 47, 14],
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
                }, {
                  label: 'RAM',
                  data: [31, 29, 31, 35, 28, 34, 30],
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                }]
              }
            });
        </script>
```

I want to change "22, 19, 25, 65, 30, 47, 14" by the new values gets with postgreSQL.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to send data to script from hapijs? And your data here `[22, 19, 25, 65, 30, 47, 14]` is dynamic?

Comment: Tank you for your answer but I find the solution by myself. I use the module vision and ejs.

Comment: Yes you have to use template engines like jade, ejs etc to server your data from hapi to client side using vision module of hapi.

Comment: Yes but now, I have an other problem ^^ If you are good with node.js maybe you be able to help me. My problem is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852380/use-local-variable-in-other-part-of-my-code

Comment: I solve this problem to.